# Samba 3.6 Configuration in Fedora 17

Tags: fedora, samba, file-sharing

I need help configuring the Samba server so I can connect from a Windows (**edit** Windows 7) machine to my Fedora. I followed several tutorials because and non of them work for me. Here are two of them:
[tutorial 1](http://www.howtoforge.com/fedora-17-samba-standalone-server-with-tdbsam-backend)
[tutorial 2](http://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Fedora_17&p=samba)
[tutorial 3 (samba and selinux)](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=277811)

Here is the fpaste of my [Samba configuration file](http://paste.fedoraproject.org/5965/13642170).

When accessing my machine by IP Windows machines see the shared folders `allusers` and `Share`.

1. When trying to open `allusers` folder it asks the user to provide username and password. I've created a test user and added it to users group + samba's users but it's not working with it (meaning It doesn't accept it).
2. When user tries to open the `Share` folder there is a message saying that he doesn't have permissions to open the folder. The folder is in 777 mod + SELinux is disabled + I allowed the Samba, Samba Client, Echo Reply (pong) and Echo Response (ping) to pass the firewall.

Can you point where is my mistake or give me some direction, please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of windows are you running? I'm going to guess 7

Comment: Your guess is correct. Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that you are running Windows 7. Do the following

Run gpedit.msc
Console Root -> Local Computer Policy -> Computer Configuration -> Windows Settings -> -> Security Settings -> Local Policies ->Security Options
Microsoft network client: Send unencrypted password to third-party SMB server: Switch it to "Enabled".
Network security: LAN Manager authentication level: Select the option: Send LM & NTLM - use NTLMv2 session security if negotiated.

Comment: I tried it just now but no result... :(
Still getting the "..you do not have permission to access"

Comment: I had a problem with the security mod - it was set to share but when change it to user and added new user to samba it worked. Thanks for the settings. It helped a lot :)